# How to get screenshot for 5.5" screen size in Xcode 15 on sonoma

Tags: ios, app-store, simulator, xcode15

**Problem definition:**

Appstore demands 5.5" screenshot.

I need a simulator at that screen size.

So it must be one of these.

- iPhone 8 Plus
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 6s Plus

Latest Xcode v15 simulator comes with support to only ios17

Since those 3 phones does not have ios17 support, the simulator app does not let me create it...

So what should I do other than taking ss of "iPhone SE" and resizing it to "iPhone 8 Plus"

Thanks

Comment: Xcode -> Settings -> Platforms. Download iOS an 15 or 16 simulator. Then you can create iPhone 6s+, 7+, or 8+ simulator devices. If your app has a deployment target of iOS 15 or 16 then you need them anyway to do some testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to install a previously released runtime.

In Xcode's menu bar, click: Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators tab -> + button at bottom (to create a new simulator)

Then select:

- Device Type: iPhone 8 Plus
- OS version: Download more simulator runtimes...

You'll be brought to the Platforms tab in Xcode preferences. Click the + button at the bottom left and select iOS. You can use the menu to install your desired previously-released iOS runtime.

After installing this runtime, you should be able to set up a new simulator with that runtime selected.